# Set div 50% height of parent div

Tags: html, css

I want the child div to be a 50% height of the parent, so if the parent div was 100%, the child div would be 50%, if the parent div was 1000px, the child div would still be 50%.

Here's a basic fiddle of what i've done so far http://jsfiddle.net/6PA6k/17/

Here's the html

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="button"></div
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
.button-container {
  height:100%;
  width:50px;
}
.button {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *parent* and *child* BTW Set `height: 100%` or whatever to *parent*, `height: 50%;` to the child.

Comment: It seems you mixed 'px' with '%'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATED

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6PA6k/22/

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height:80%;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
.button-container {
    position: relative;
    height:50%;
    width:300px;
    background:blue;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
    margin-top: -25px;
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I want, maybe i didn't explain myself correctly. I want a button 50px x 50px 50% of the height of the parent div.

Comment: a 50px x 50px button needs to float 50% height of the container, for instance a red background with a 50px x 50px square in the middle (height)

Answer (score 2):

I may be confused about what you are asking, but changing:

```
.button {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

To:

```
.button {
  width:50px;
  height:50%;
  background:blue;
}
```

Does what you seem to want... http://jsfiddle.net/c3eB8/

**EDIT**

Ok, so now that I understand the question better, in order to center the child div vertically with a parent div without fixed dimensions, you can use absolute positioning.

```
.button {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8UjvB/

Comment: Not quite, maybe i didn't explain myself correctly. I want a button 50px x 50px 50% of the height of the parent div.

Comment: You mean you want a 50x50px button floating in the middle of a div which occupies 50% of the parent div?

Comment: @user1221565 I don't quite get it, do you want the button positioned in the middle (50%) of the parent div, or do you want it to be half (50%) the size of the parent div?

Comment: Basically I want a 50px x 50px div which floats in the middle (height) of the parent div

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/8p5MT/

It places the 50x50 button in the middle of the parent:

```
.button-container {
    height:100%;
    width:50px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
}
.button {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

(add `position:relative` to the parent, and `margin:auto; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0` to the `.button` statement)